# Enabling Search Bar Functionality for Network Shared Files on Windows

Tags: windows, search

I have a specific question regarding the functionality of the search bar on my Windows machine. Previously, when searching for files that were included on my PC, they would automatically appear when entered into the search bar. However, my concern now is whether it's possible to search for files located on a public network shared folder and have them appear in the search results on my PC. I would appreciate it if there's a way to enable these files to show up in search results on my own PC.
I'm open to using any software if it can help resolve this issue.

Thanks for taking care of this.